# gnome-session: where to put "--disable-acceleration-check"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome

After I've install properitary nvidia drivers in my Ubuntu 14.04.5 (Kernel 4.4.0), I am not longer able to start the display manager or remote session via thinlinc. `/var/log/syslog` reports

```
gnome-session[4058]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Der Childprocess exited with status 1
gnome-session[4058]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Concerning this post [1], it is possible to bypass the acceleration check, but I don't know where to put the flag `--disable-acceleration-check`.
Can someone help?

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1251281

Answer (score 1):

Building on [DomQ's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012456) above, try this for `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98-gnome-session-disable-acceleration-check`

```
case "$STARTUP" in
     *gnome-session*)
       STARTUP="$STARTUP --disable-acceleration-check"
       ;;
     *x-session-manager*)
       if $(/usr/bin/update-alternatives --query x-session-manager|grep -q "^Value:.*gnome-session")
       then
         STARTUP="$STARTUP --disable-acceleration-check"
       fi
       ;;
esac
```

Edit: it looks like `update-alternatives` is located in `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/sbin` in recent versions of Ubuntu.  I've updated the above script to match the new location.  If you're not sure where update-alternatives is on your system, try running "which update-alternatives" in a terminal window.

Comment: I created this file, but still get the same error. I should note that it says 'gnome-session-binary[2186]' for me instead of 'gnome-session[4058]', would that make a difference?

Comment: @Luuk It looks like update-alternatives may be in a different location than I specified in the script.  I changed "/usr/sbin/update-alternatives" to "/usr/bin/update-alternatives".  Try that and see if it works.  To answer your question about gnome-session-binary, that shouldn't make a difference.  As long as the string "gnome-session" is in the name, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I adjusted the file but it still had no effect unfortunately. Is it only needed to create and save the file, or does it need to be run?

Comment: You just need to create and save the file.  It should be run automatically when Gnome starts up.  If you've set up the file and rebooted and it still doesn't work, then I don't know what else might help.

Comment: Thanks.  Used this for xrdp to an ubuntu client on virtualbox.  (16.04, needed /usr/sbin/update-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/98-gnome-session-disable-acceleration-check` containing

```
case "$STARTUP" in
     *gnome-session*)
       STARTUP="$STARTUP --disable-acceleration-check"
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: I made the above file but still get the same error when I try to connect windows subsystem for Linux from vnc viewer.

Comment: There's a problem with this answer.  Xsession doesn't run gnome-session by name.  It runs x-session-manager, which is usually an alias to gnome-session.  I posted another answer based on this one.  (I don't know if that's proper StackExchange etiquette.  Should I have edited your answer instead?)