# 'gnome-session' command does not start up GUI anymore after updating Ubuntu, returns GLXBadFBConfig error

Tags: gnome, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnome-session

I am using Ubuntu on Windows with WSL. After updating Ubuntu to the latest version (20.04.3 LTS I believe) I am not able to run the gnome-session command anymore, which would usually allow me to access a GUI on VcXsrv. When I run the command it simply returns without starting up the GUI. This has happened before, however restarting Windows once usually resolved the issue.
Running `gnome-session --debug` returns the following:

```
gnome-session-binary[463]: DEBUG(+): Enabling debugging
gnome-session-binary[463]: GLib-DEBUG(+): posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)

(gnome-session-check-accelerated:466): Gdk-ERROR **: 18:14:00.423: The program 'gnome-session-check-accelerated' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadFBConfig'.
  (Details: serial 187 error_code 163 request_code 149 (GLX) minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
gnome-session-binary[463]: DEBUG(+): hardware acceleration check failed: Child process killed by signal 5
gnome-session-binary[463]: GLib-DEBUG(+): setenv()/putenv() are not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
gnome-session-binary[463]: GLib-DEBUG(+): posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)

(gnome-session-check-accelerated:469): Gdk-ERROR **: 18:14:00.608: The program 'gnome-session-check-accelerated' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadFBConfig'.
  (Details: serial 187 error_code 163 request_code 149 (GLX) minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
gnome-session-binary[463]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process killed by signal 5
gnome-session-binary[463]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Note that these errors only come up when VcXsrv is also opened.

Comment: Don't have experience with this one myself, but it sounds like [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/832197/1165986) might help?

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work, but possibly that could be because my error seems to be slightly different (originating in gnome-session-binary instead of gnome-session).